# Plotting Key-Value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot key-value pairs in a dictionary. The problem is that my values are lists, each containing hundreds of data points. I need to plot these against the key (which represents years). I have a sample pic ([Attached here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80v29.png) from a thesis that I'm basing my work on. I need to be able plot like that. All of the data points in a value against it's key (year).

If my dictionary is d,
I tried the following:

```
f=list(d.items())
plt.plot(f[0][0],f[0][1])
```

But I get the following error:

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (408,)

Please let me know if there is any way I can plot it such that I can get a plot similar to the one attached. Thanks in advance.

PS. The sample plot was done using IDL, in case anyone wants to know since it doesn't look like a python plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding multiple y-values to the same point on the x-Axis, you need to bring the x-Value to the same dimension as the y-Value:

```
y = [[5,1,2,3,9,10],[1,1,5,7.2,3.4,9,6.6,2,4]]
x = ['2000','2001']

for x_val, y_val in zip(x, y): # Getting related pairs from x and y
    plt.scatter([x_val] * len(y_val), y_val) # Bumping the dimension of x_val to the dimension of y_val before plotting

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Finished plot]

So for your problem you might try doing it like that:

```
f=list(d.items())
x = f[0][0]
y = f[0][1]

for x_val, y_val in zip(x, y):
    plt.scatter([x_val]
```

Comment: Ah, thanks man. That worked like a charm. The problem seems silly now once I understood what had to be done. xD

Comment: Glad it helped :)